# Python Object as list in dictionary

Tags: python, list, object, dictionary

I am in python and I have this:

```
places = [{'placeId':5},{'placeId':2}]
```

and this(note that the workout has a lot more data than 'To' and 'Exercise'.. I didnt wrote them all):

```
workout={'To': 'John' , 'Exercise': 'pull-ups'}
```

and I want to make this:

```
Emailwork={'To': 'John' , 'Exercise': 'pull-ups', 'places':[5,2]}
```

Can I have some help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension listed in your dictionary in order to retrieve the values:

```
workout = {'To': 'John' , 'Exercise': 'pull-ups', 'places': [i['placeId'] for i in places]}
```

Comment: Sorry my friend but I edited my question a bit.. and I would also prefer a more pythonic way to do it.. cause the data are too many and I cant just add at the end of the dictionary the 'places'.

Comment: I used in first place your (('places': [i['placeId'] for i in places])) to make places a list.... Now I need a pythonic way to add the 'places':[5,2] in the end of the workout thing..

Comment: This works as is. You're problem is that a dictionary is not ordered, meaning that places, exercise, and to can appear in any order when printed.

Comment: you are right.. I append the list in the workout with workout['places']=places .. and everything is working correctly now.. thank you!